# Write CloudPage URL into Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, cloudpagesurl

I have a dynamic CloudPage that, based on URL parameters, will populate a specific sport's sign-up page (baseball, basketball, etc). We've seen some spotty issues recently, but have been unable to pinpoint which sign-up is causing issues, so we are hoping that, upon submission of the CloudPage, we can write the URL into the data extension as well.

Is this possible? If so, how would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page, you can use

```
%%[SET @mypageURL = RequestParameter("PageURL")]%%
```

...which will contain the page's own url, and you can send that along with your other data, put it in a DE or similar.

Note you have to test this on an actual live page, preview shows you something else like:

`http://intsvc-s50.xt.local/internalservice/v1/CloudPages/Preview/3.`

If you are interested in the cloudpage Id, you can simply use `@tabId` (without RequestParameter), this variable just "exists", and you can output it / use it to log into data extensions etc. Similar, live page or it won't work.

```
%%=v(@tabid)=%%
```

Comment: Jonas, thank you! This nearly has me there. Apologies, as I am not a developer. 

Our sign-up page is the page where the user can enter their info. I placed the script you added above and when I click 'View Page Source' it works as expected. However, we also have a 'processing' page which is the 'Thank you' page and submits the field info. I put what I thought was necessary there, but it's populating the 'Thank you' page URL rather than the Sign-Up page URL.

Comment: The code I posted has to go on the sign up page. This is where you request the pageURL parameter and put it into a variable (lets call it `@formPage`) as a value with this code. You got this far already. You have to send that variable along to the handler page as a parameter -> then ,on your handler, you do `RequestParameter("formPage")`, which will contain the value of the form page URL (=what you want), not the handler's.

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you so much!